# spring: is not a valid value for 'NCName'

Tags: java, spring

The schema:

```
 <util:list id="Handlers">
  <ref local="#{stageFactory}.#{regionFactory}.Handlers"/>
</util:list>
```

The error:

`'#{stageFactory}.#{regionFactory}.Handlers' is not a valid value for 'NCName'.`